# Keep process running while program continues C++

Tags: python, c++

I want to be able to call a function in a python script through C++. The function will print some text to stdout.

However, the python script takes about 1 minute to load the global variables to memory, so I want to keep the process alive in interactive mode, where I would be able to simply call the function again without loading all the variables again.

I know that I can run system commands using [system](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/), but the command must terminate before I can use the output. I am also aware that I can use CPython and call `PyRun_SimpleFileEx` on the file, but this will have to reload all the variables again

I don't have any code to show since I don't know how to do this. Is there any way I can do this without rewriting the whole python script in C++?

Comment: So you have a method that uses these global variables but you want to load these variables only once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Can you edit the script to expose the code you want to call several times as a function?

Comment: The code I want to run several times is already a function in Python. However, it relies on some global variables, which are slow to load. I want to call the function from a C++ program. I hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every `PyRun_*` function runs in the `__main__` module, so any functions or variables you define stick around for future executions.

For example, say we want to run the `do_it` function from this file (helper.py) multiple times:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt
from time import sleep
print("First load")

def do_it():
    print("Helper function called on demand: %s" % dt.now())
    sleep(1)

do_it()
```

We can simply invoke `PyRun_SimpleFile` once, and then access the function again using `PyRun_SimpleString("do_it()\n");`.

```c
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    wchar_t *program = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[0], NULL);
    if (program == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: cannot decode argv[0]\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    Py_SetProgramName(program);  /* optional but recommended */
    Py_Initialize();
    FILE *fp = fopen("helper.py", "rb");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, "helper.py");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        PyRun_SimpleString("do_it()\n");
    }
    if (Py_FinalizeEx() < 0) {
        exit(120);
    }
    PyMem_RawFree(program);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this makes use of the "Very High Level Embedding" and is thus limited to evaluating strings. For more complex arguments you may want to use the ["Pure embedding"](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#pure-embedding) instead to grab the `PyFunctionObject` from the module and invoke it.

Finally, you may want to look at [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11), a C++11 bridge between Python and C++. This should make it very easy to grab Python the function and call it directly from C++.